# How do I troubleshoot an NPE when creating my activity in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception

I'm getting an NPE when I start an activity in my application.  It doesn't happen right away when I boot my phone and start debugging on it.  After several dozen new builds are pushed to my phone it eventually starts crashing with this error every single time.  I can remedy it temporarily by opening a few other activities first before I activate the errant one.

Any ideas what could cause this?  It's a somewhat complicated Activity with a DrawerLayout, and a fragment that contains a SwipeRefreshLayout with a ListView.

**Exception**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'boolean android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.mAddToBackStack' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1279)
```

**Activity Code**

```
public class TastingsActivity extends BaseActivity implements TastingListFragment.Callbacks {
    public static final String TAG = TastingsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private TastingListFragment mTastingListFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tastings);

        //create fragment
        // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
        // the fragment_container FrameLayout
        if (findViewById(R.id.container) != null) {

            // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
            TastingListFragment fragment = new TastingListFragment();

            // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an
            // Intent, pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
            fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected int getSelfNavDrawerItem() {
        return NAVDRAWER_ITEM_TASTINGS;
    }

    //================================================================================
    // Handlers
    //================================================================================

    @Override
    public void onTastingSelected(Tasting tasting) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TastingActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(TastingDetailsFragment.EXTRA_TASTING_ID, tasting.getId());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your Activity Code.

Comment: Need your code to identify issues. Did you identify scenario on which this issues occurs.

Comment: I added the code for the activity.  I have several other activities using the parent activity so I don't think it's the cause.  I can post its code also if needed.

Comment: The problem is in Adding Fragment to BackStack

Comment: I posted the code to the wrong activity.  This is the one that's causing the error.

Comment: i have the same error, you identify the problem?

Comment: I did, though I don't remember what it was.  I solved it by adding an exception breakpoint for that specific exception, and changing it from `thread` to `all`.  Hope this helps!